# How to compile in Fortran in order to use an add-on in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

I need to use the r.inund.fluv add-on in GRASS. I installed the gfortran compiler in order to use the script. The problem is, I do not know how to compile the files in gfortran. Im using windows

Here are the [files for r.inund.fluv.](https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/raster/r.inund.fluv/)

I emailed the author of the script, Roberto Marzocchi and he instructed me to do the following and I was stuck at step 4.:

Try the following way:

1) save the file r.inund.fluv within the folder named scripts within the grass main folder

2) create a file r.inund.fluv.bat in the folder named bin and copy the following row:

```
@"%GRASS_SH%" -c '"%GISBASE%/scripts/r.inund.fluv" %*'
```

3) save the file r.inund.fluv.html within the folder named doc

4) create a folder named fortran_code within your etc folder and save the four fortran code 2d_path.f90, etc etc. then try to compile the 4 fortran codes using for the binary file the same name of the source code without any extension  e.g (2d_path.f90 become 2d_path)

Comment: +1 for being the first to mention Fortran on this site and for being brave enough to dive in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about f90 -o 2d_path 2d_path.f90 ?

Comment: I tried running it and it produced this error: `C:\Program Files\GRASS-64\etc\fortran_code>gfortran -o 2d_path 2d_path.f90
C:\Program Files\gfortran\bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file 2d_path.exe: Permi
ssion denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Do you have permission to write in that directory?

Comment: Thanks. I had already resolved it by placing it first in a public directory so that I can compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful Link
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran

Compilers for Windows:
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#Windows